# what is the vim native key comb that will show what is received on next input?

Tags: vim, key, neovim, built-in

I forgot the key combination for this functionality and I tried to search a bit unfortunately to no avail.

I think it was actually a super simple combination of control or shift with a letter key. The next input in the editor will show the received key.

Comment: Do you mean Ctrl-V (insert next non-numeric keypress literally)?

Comment: yes exactly! It needs to be executed in insert mode is another thing that went off my mind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It also works in command mode. But not in normal. `:help i_CTRL-V`, `:help c_CTRL-V`.

Comment: @Amadan "command-line mode". Also, you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In command-line mode and insert mode, Ctrl-V is used to insert the next non-numeric keypress literally (i.e. not as a Vim movement or mapping, for example), or to enter a character by its numerical value. E.g.

- <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will input a CR character (which Vim typically displays as `^M`)
- <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> will input a Tab character, even if the `expandtabs` option is set
- <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> will input the text `<Right>`, since there is no one character associated with the right arrow key
- <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> will input `A`, whose ASCII value is `65`
- <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> will insert a poop emoji after you have typed a non-hex-digit

More info at `:help i_CTRL-V`, `:help i_CTRL-V_digit`, and equivalent command-line mode topic `:help c_CTRL-V`.